# Premature blueberries dropping buds

Tags: blueberries

Blueberry flowers are dropping off. I raise mason bees so, I know pollination is not the cause, and Lane County Oregon has had an over abundance of rain.
I am baffled. Last year I had a bumper crop. **What gives?**

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if there were any freezes at night?  Doesn't take much dipping n the temperatures to cause plants to do wig out. My blueberries last year got a few sudden freezes, they were acclimated but all the buds fell off. Please send pictures and more information.  Lane county, huh!  I am in Deschutes county south of Bend.  I had bumper crops for the first 3 years and this last year zilch...all the flower buds dropped off.  The temperature change between day and night time is humongous.  Just one freeze at night that you might not even notice will kill the flower buds. Hopefully they'll recoup and get a second chance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are not too wet? I have some in a container and have poor drainage after lots of heavy rain which made them look sick, so I pulled all the compost out, put in fresh and drilled extra drainage holes.